# Rappasoft Laravel Livewire Datatables, Job table with a column that count work items and should be sortable

Tags: laravel, datatables

My Issue,

I'm working on showing a Jobs table in my laravel app. I decided to use rappasoft/laravel-livewire-datatablles to render the table and I'm pleasently surprised at how simple this is to use!

However I now have an issue I've been unable to resolve. I have a column which I label WI (for work items) and each row contains a count of work items associated to the job.

My Job model has a function to get the work items so in general I can use $job->workItems->count() to get the count of items.

```
public function workItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany( JobWorkItem::class, 'job_number', 'number' );
    }
```

I have my datatable called All that shows all jobs:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Tables\Job;

use App\Models\Job;
use App\Models\WorkGroup;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Rappasoft\LaravelLivewireTables\DataTableComponent;
use Rappasoft\LaravelLivewireTables\Views\Column;
use Rappasoft\LaravelLivewireTables\Views\Columns\LinkColumn;
use Rappasoft\LaravelLivewireTables\Views\Filters\DateFilter;
use Rappasoft\LaravelLivewireTables\Views\Filters\MultiSelectFilter;
use Rappasoft\LaravelLivewireTables\Views\Filters\SelectFilter;

class All extends DataTableComponent
{
    public string $tableName = 'jobs';
    public array $jobs = [];

    public $columnSearch = [
        'client' => null,
        'title' => null,
    ];
    public function builder(): Builder
    {
        return Job::query()
            ->select(['*', DB::raw('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM job_work_items WHERE job_number = jobs.number) as wi_count')])
            ->where( 'is_draft', 0 )
            ->where( 'redirect', 0 )
            ->with( 'client' )
            ->orderBy( 'number', 'desc')
            ->when(
                $this->columnSearch['client'] ?? null,
                fn ($query, $title) => $query->where('clients.title', 'like', '%' . $title . '%')
            )
            ->when(
                $this->columnSearch['title'] ?? null,
                fn ($query, $title) => $query->where('jobs.title', 'like', '%' . $title . '%')
            );
    }
    public function configure(): void
    {
        $this->setPrimaryKey('number')
            ->setReorderDisabled()
            ->setSingleSortingEnabled()
            ->setHideReorderColumnUnlessReorderingEnabled()
            ->setFilterLayoutSlideDown()
            ->setRememberColumnSelectionDisabled()
            ->setSecondaryHeaderTrAttributes(function($rows) {
                return ['class' => 'bg-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-800'];
            })
            ->setSecondaryHeaderTdAttributes(function(Column $column, $rows) {
                if ($column->isField('number')) {
                    return ['class' => 'text-red-500'];
                }

                return ['default' => true];
            })
            ->setFooterTrAttributes(function($rows) {
                return ['class' => 'bg-gray-100'];
            })
            ->setFooterTdAttributes(function(Column $column, $rows) {
                if ($column->isField('name')) {
                    return ['class' => 'text-green-500'];
                }

                return ['default' => true];
            })
            ->setUseHeaderAsFooterEnabled()
            ->setBulkActionsEnabled();
//        $this->setDebugEnabled();
    }

    public function columns(): array
    {
        return [
            Column::make( 'Job Number', 'number')
                ->sortable()
                ->searchable()
                ->format(function( $number ) {
                    return '<a href="/job/' . $number . '/show">#' . sprintf( '%07d', $number ) . '</a>';
                })
                ->html(),

            LinkColumn::make('Client')
                ->sortable()
                ->searchable()
                ->title(fn($row) => $row->client->title)
                ->location(fn($row) =>  '/client/' . $row->client->id . '/show'),

            Column::make('Title', 'title')
                ->sortable()
                ->searchable(),

//            Column::make('WI')
//                ->sortable()
//                ->format(function($job) {
//                    return $job->workItems->count();
//                }),

            Column::make('WI', 'number')
                ->sortable()
                ->format(function($number) {
                    return Job::find($number)->workItems->count();
                }),

            Column::make('...', 'number' )
                ->view('tables.job.actions'),
        ];
    }

    public function filters(): array
    {
        return [
            MultiSelectFilter::make('Work Group')
                ->options(
                    WorkGroup::query()
                        ->orderBy('title')
                        ->get()
                        ->keyBy('work_group')
                        ->map(fn($workGroup) => $workGroup->title)
                        ->toArray()
                )->filter(function(Builder $builder, array $values) {
                    $builder->whereHas('work_group', fn($query) => $query->whereIn('work_group.id', $values));
                })
                ->setFilterPillValues([
                    '3' => 'Web',
                ]),
            SelectFilter::make('E-mail Verified', 'email_verified_at')
                ->setFilterPillTitle('Verified')
                ->options([
                    ''    => 'Any',
                    'yes' => 'Yes',
                    'no'  => 'No',
                ])
                ->filter(function(Builder $builder, string $value) {
                    if ($value === 'yes') {
                        $builder->whereNotNull('email_verified_at');
                    } elseif ($value === 'no') {
                        $builder->whereNull('email_verified_at');
                    }
                }),
            SelectFilter::make('Active')
                ->setFilterPillTitle('User Status')
                ->setFilterPillValues([
                    '1' => 'Active',
                    '0' => 'Inactive',
                ])
                ->options([
                    '' => 'All',
                    '1' => 'Yes',
                    '0' => 'No',
                ])
                ->filter(function(Builder $builder, string $value) {
                    if ($value === '1') {
                        $builder->where('active', true);
                    } elseif ($value === '0') {
                        $builder->where('active', false);
                    }
                }),
            DateFilter::make('Edit From')
                ->config([
                    'min' => '2020-01-01',
                    'max' => '2021-12-31',
                ])
                ->filter(function(Builder $builder, string $value) {
                    $builder->where('updated_at', '>=', $value);
                }),
            DateFilter::make('Edit To')
                ->filter(function(Builder $builder, string $value) {
                    $builder->where('updated_at', '<=', $value);
                }),
        ];
    }

    public function bulkActions(): array
    {
        return [
            'activate' => 'Activate',
            'deactivate' => 'Deactivate',
        ];
    }

    public function activate()
    {
        User::whereIn('id', $this->getSelected())->update(['is_enabled' => true]);

        $this->clearSelected();
    }

    public function deactivate()
    {
        User::whereIn('id', $this->getSelected())->update(['is_enabled' => false]);

        $this->clearSelected();
    }

    public function reorder($items): void
    {
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            User::find((int)$item['value'])->update(['sort' => (int)$item['order']]);
        }
    }
}
```

This shows the number of work items but it doesn't sort the order if i try to sort by the column. As can be seen from the code above there is another method I have tried but this gives an error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'jobs.w_i' in 'field list' (Connection: mysql, SQL: select *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM job_work_items WHERE job_number = jobs.number) as wi_count, `jobs`.`number` as `number`, `jobs`.`title` as `title`, `jobs`.`w_i` as `w_i` from `jobs` where `is_draft` = 0 and `redirect` = 0 order by `number` desc, `number` desc limit 10 offset 10)
```

How can I fix this so it is able to sort by the number of work items for a job?

Answer (score 1):

So I spent a lot of time with ChatGPT with little to no success with this and a lot of chasing ones tail... In the end I applied the gray matter and got it working with this

```
            Column::make('W.I.', 'work_items_count')
                ->label(function ( $row ) {
                    return $row->work_items_count;
                })
                ->sortable(),
```

and updating builder by adding `->withCount('workItems')`